# Replacing \n in csv file

Tags: linux, unix

I've got a csv file from an mysql export with user content. If an user enters a return, I can't import the csv correctly to another system. So I need to replace the `\n`. This wouldn't be a problem, but at the end of the line, there's also a `\n` which I won't replace.

Here's a sample:

```
   john;doe;false;this \n is \n a \n comment;\n
   james;bond;true;;\n
```

So how can I replace just all the `\n` in the comment column of the csv file? I know I could edit the last new line because it's allways after an semi-colon and replace then all other returns with `tr -d '\n' < file.csv`, but is there a smarter way?

thanks for any help!

---

edit: output from `cat`

```
\ohn;doe;false;This
\s
\
comment;
james;bond;true;No returns in this comment;
```

If I open the file in notepad++ or other editors, the first character after the backslash are visible. With a hex editor, it shows me a `0D0A`.

Comment: Are those `\n`s in your sample newlines or are they literal `\n` strings?

Comment: These are newlines and not strings (like it looks like..)

Comment: well, in that case, simple sed 's/\\n//g' file.csv would suffice

Comment: but this would replace all the newlines I think and I just want to keep the newlines at the end of each line

Comment: You should change your sample so that it shows what is output when your run `cat` on your file. Putting `\n` in the sample is misleading.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, now there's the same output as cat gives

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I've found a solution. I delete all the unnecessary `newlines` directly in my `mysql export script`. I think this is the easiest and fastest way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

This should work :

```
  perl -pe 's/(?<\!;)\n//g' file.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 sed "s/\\\n$//g" mycsvfile

mycsvfile means the file name of the csv file
```

Comment: is there a mistake in your syntax? It doesn't replace anything in my file.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following `awk` command:

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS=";\n";FS=";";OFS=";";ORS=";\n"}{gsub("\n","",$4);print}' file
```

Output:

```
$ cat file
john;doe;false;this
is
a
comment;
james;bond;true;;


$ awk 'BEGIN{RS=";\n";FS=";";OFS=";";ORS=";\n"}{gsub("\n","",$4);print}' file
john;doe;false;this is a comment;
james;bond;true;;
```

Comment: if I run the `awk command` as you stated, i get the following result (new line after This): \comment;false;This
james;bond;true;No returns in this comment;